# Json is not being written to file

Tags: java, android, json, file, filewriter

I've taken input from editText and trying to write its text to a json file. When I execute the code, it works without any errors. But when I try to read the json file again it doesn't have the previously written objects.

I've tried using different writers like BufferedWriter, FileWriter. None of them works.

This is the writeToJsonFile method

```
void writeJsonFile(TextView textView) {
        String json;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("chores.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            if (is.read(buffer) == -1) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject m_jArray = obj.getJSONObject("chores");
            JSONArray jsonArray = m_jArray.getJSONArray(title);

            JSONObject new_jobj = new JSONObject();
            new_jobj.put("task", textView.getText());
            new_jobj.put("isCompleted", false);

            jsonArray.put(new_jobj);

            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("/assets"), "chores.json");
            writeJsonFile(file, obj);
            Log.i("Done => ", "Written to file");


        } catch (EOFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This function takes a file and a json object and writes the json object to the file

```
public static void writeJsonFile(File file, JSONObject json) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    fileWriter.write(json.toString());
    if (fileWriter != null) {
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I expect it to write the json string to the file, but next time I read the file again with the InputStream, It doesn't show the previously added Object.

expected chores.json

```
{
  "chores": {
    "Daily": [
      {
        "task": "Task 1",
        "isCompleted": false
      }

    ],
    "Weekly": [

    ],
    "Monthly": [

    ],
    "Custom": [

    ]
  }
}
```

resulting json

```
{
  "chores": {
    "Daily": [

    ],
    "Weekly": [

    ],
    "Monthly": [

    ],
    "Custom": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to write jsonArray to a JSONObject and then write that JSONObject to the file.

Comment: @SriAji JSON array is already in the json object. Do I still need to put it in the obj? Doesn't it add a new array to the object? I want to add the object to the existing array.

Comment: You didn't add 'jsonArray' to anything.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not getting any exception? Can you please check your logcat and report back here. I think it is throwing an exception which is caught by your catch block and did not crash the app.

Comment: might be you are creating new file, check file path

Comment: Yeap I'm pretty sure there are no exceptions. @ReazMurshed

Comment: Both the paths are in the question. I don't know if the paths are the same or different. The debugger shows the same path though. @APP

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing newly created object into file: For example:

```
        ...
        JSONObject new_jobj = new JSONObject();
        new_jobj.put("task", textView.getText());
        new_jobj.put("isCompleted", false);

        jsonArray.put(new_jobj);

        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("/assets"), "chores.json");
        // here instead of old obj write newly created new_jobj to file.

        writeJsonFile(file, new_jobj);
        Log.i("Done => ", "Written to file");
        ...
```

Comment: This will make the json file to have only the new json object, doesn't it? I want to add it to the array in the json file.

Comment: Also, the debugger shows the obj has the new_jobj in it.

Comment: well in that case you need to modify the old json `obj` and rewrite it.

Comment: As you can see I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: well you are not updating the previous object. like: putting back newly created `jsonArray`  into `obj`. Try put `jsonArray` into `obj` and your problem should solve.

Comment: the put method of the obj doesn't take an array as it's parameter it only takes an object.

Comment: it would be better if you just add the current `chores.json` and expectd `chores.json` into question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196234/discussion-between-koushik-bhargava-and-ruhul).

Answer (score 0):

Before that make sure you have **`read and write storage permisions`**....

**`Ex.`**

```
try 
{
    Writer output = null;
    File file = new File("filePath");
    if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    output.write(jsonObject.toString());
    output.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Tried, not working. And I have given the read and write permission.

Comment: @KoushikBhargava make sure log the jsonObject data is present or not and check in directory file created or not

Comment: When I go to the path of the assets folder in my android device, there it doesn't show the chores.json file

Comment: @KoushikBhargava check before writing to file file is exist or not if exist then log the file path

Answer (score -1):

You can use the append property  in FileWriter constructor. You can try it.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
```